# Send my message only to subscribed server and not to my other servers

Tags: node.js, redis, server, socket.io

How do I send my message that is published to a Redis channel only to subscribed server (which is connected to the subscriber) and not to my other servers (where the required subscriber isn't connected).

I'm using Socket.IO and Redis server.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve this article might help - [link](https://www.compose.com/articles/redis-pubsub-node-and-socket-io/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)?

> not programmed to send their messages to specific receivers (subscribers). Rather, published messages are characterized into channels, without knowledge of what (if any) subscribers there may be

I other words, you cannot target a specific subscriber.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can consider using multiple channels, with each consumer using its own.